# How to integrate this area?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to find the following area between the shapes made by $r=3+2\sin{t}$ and $r=2$:

[image]

My problem is if I need to integrate with any function or not. First, to check the angle I just did $2=r=3+2\sin{t} \Rightarrow \sin{t} = -\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow$ the angle goes from $\frac{7\pi}{6}$ and $\frac{11\pi}{6}$. For the radius, it's from $2$ to $3+2 \sin{t}$. My problem is in the integrals.

It it $\int^{\frac{11\pi}{6}}_{\frac{7\pi}{6}} \int^{3+2 \sin{\theta}}_{2} (1) r drd\theta$? Or $\int^{\frac{11\pi}{6}}_{\frac{7\pi}{6}} \int^{3+2 \sin{\theta}}_{2} (3+2 \sin{\theta} )r drd\theta$?

Comment: You need to work out $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{7\pi/6}^{11\pi/6}(3+2\sin\theta)^2\mathrm{d}\theta-\frac{1}{2}\int_{7\pi/6}^{11\pi/6}2^2 \mathrm{d}\theta.$$

Comment: Thanks. Your comment immediately got me confused but I searched a little bit what you're referring. It's the formula Area $ = \frac{1}{2} \int^{\beta}_{\alpha} r^2 d\theta$, right? And then, with the subtraction, since we already got the angles I don't need to worry abut subtracting more than needed?

Comment: Basically what I'm doing is finding the area of the entire cardioid within that angle range and then subtracting the area of the circular sector. And yes, I'm using the regular polar angle formula.

Comment: Indeed. I think you're right. The answer is supposed to be $24.187$ but your expression doesn't give that result. I think the answers are wrong because you make total sense. Do you think there's another way to get to $24.187$?

Comment: I just figured it out. Not only were the bounds of the integral backwards but its better to convert angles. That is, $11\pi/6\to -\pi/6.$ Then we calculate
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi/6}^{7\pi/6}(3+2\sin\theta)^2\mathrm{d}\theta-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi/6}^{7\pi/6}2^2\mathrm{d}\theta\approx 24.187.$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following diagram. Here $dθ$ is the infinitesimally small angle such that we the variation of $r$ with $θ$ can be neglected.

[image]

Clearly, we need to find the summation (integral) of the orange areas :

[image]

Now consider the following diagrams:

[image]

[image]

Our Orange area = Blue Area - Green Area

Also, the figures can be approximated as sectors of a circle as the variation of $r$ with $θ$ is negligible.

So, the Orange area,

$$dA=\frac{1}{2}\left(r_{blue}\right)^{2}d\theta\ -\ \frac{1}{2}\left(r_{green}\right)^{2}d\theta$$

$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{7\pi}{6}}dA=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{7\pi}{6}}\frac{1}{2}\left(3+2\sin\theta\right)^{2}d\theta\ -\ \int_{-\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{7\pi}{6}}\frac{1}{2}\left(2\right)^{2}d\theta$$

Which comes out to be approximately as $24.1870451584$